# What is creating vertical space in the first two columns?

Tags: vertical-alignment, vwcol

I'm using the vwcol package, which I know has issues processing stuff that isn't plain text. Is there something I could do to fix the vertical spacing?

[image: photo of example]

```
\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.35,0.35,0.3}]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}

    From rectangular to spherical:

    $$\begin{bmatrix}
        A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \!=\!
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \sin\theta \cos\phi & \sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta \\
        \cos\theta \cos\phi & \cos\theta \sin\phi & -\sin\theta \\
        -\sin\phi           & \cos\phi            & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
    \!\begin{bmatrix}
        A_{x} \\ A_{y} \\ A_{z}
    \end{bmatrix}$$

    From spherical to rectangular:

    $$\begin{bmatrix}
        A_{x} \\A_{y} \\ A_{z}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \!=\!
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \sin\theta \cos\phi & \cos\theta \cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\
        \sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta \sin\phi & \cos\phi \\
        \cos\theta          & -\sin\theta         & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
    \!\begin{bmatrix}
        A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
    \end{bmatrix}$$

    From cylindrical to spherical:

    $\begin{bmatrix}
        A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \!=\!
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta \\ 
        \cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta \\ 
        0          & 1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
    \!\begin{bmatrix}
        A_{\rho} \\ A_{\phi} \\ A_{z}
    \end{bmatrix}$

\end{vwcol}
```

Comment: please provide a test document. Why `$$` for some and `$` for the last? (`$$` should not be used in latex)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The provided answers are much more elaborate than I think necessary.  Since you are using `amsmath` (evident from your use of `bmatrix`), don't use `$$` for your display equations; instead, use `\[ ... \]`.  And, more important, do *not* leave a blank line between text and display.  That gives a paragraph break, where the space above the display can stretch quite a bit, depending on what else is on the page.  (I'm not able to test at the moment, so won't address horizontal spacing.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a compelling need for the `vwcol` package. However, I do think it's necessary to employ `\footnotesize` (for a 20% linear reduction in font size) in order to make the three expressions fit inside the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' env.
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % optional

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next 3 instructions

\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default: 5pt
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}   % default: 6pt
\footnotesize

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{c}
From rectangular to spherical\\[2ex]
$ \begin{bmatrix}
  A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
  \end{bmatrix}
  {=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \sin\theta \cos\phi & \sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta \\
  \cos\theta \cos\phi & \cos\theta \sin\phi & -\sin\theta \\
  -\sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0
  \end{bmatrix}\!
  \begin{bmatrix}
  A_{x} \\ A_{y} \\ A_{z} 
  \end{bmatrix}$
\end{tabular}% 
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{c}
From spherical to rectangular\\[2ex]
$ \begin{bmatrix}
  A_{x} \\A_{y} \\ A_{z}
  \end{bmatrix}
  {=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \sin\theta \cos\phi & \cos\theta \cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\
  \sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta \sin\phi & \cos\phi \\
  \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0
  \end{bmatrix}\!
  \begin{bmatrix}
  A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
  \end{bmatrix}$
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{c}
From cylindrical to spherical\\[2ex]
$ \begin{bmatrix}
  A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
  \end{bmatrix}
  {=}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta \\ 
  \cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta \\ 
  0 & 1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}\!
  \begin{bmatrix}
  A_{\rho} \\ A_{\phi} \\ A_{z}
  \end{bmatrix}$
\end{tabular}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not telling about the geometry of your pages: that input is definitely too wide for a regular text width.

The simplest method is to use `tabular` for the three objects, so they can be placed in different ways depending on your available text width.

#### Very wide, needs `\footnotesize`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
From rectangular to spherical: \\[1ex]
$\!
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \sin\theta \cos\phi & \sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta \\
   \cos\theta \cos\phi & \cos\theta \sin\phi & -\sin\theta \\
   -\sin\phi           & \cos\phi            & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{x} \\ A_{y} \\ A_{z}
 \end{bmatrix}
$
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
From spherical to rectangular: \\[1ex]
$\!
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{x} \\A_{y} \\ A_{z}
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \sin\theta \cos\phi & \cos\theta \cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\
   \sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta \sin\phi & \cos\phi \\
   \cos\theta          & -\sin\theta         & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
 \end{bmatrix}
$
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
From cylindrical to spherical: \\[1ex]
$\!
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta \\ 
   \cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta \\ 
   0          & 1 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{\rho} \\ A_{\phi} \\ A_{z}
 \end{bmatrix}
$
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### A bit wider than standard, `\small` suffices

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
From rectangular to spherical: \\[1ex]
$\!
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \sin\theta \cos\phi & \sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta \\
   \cos\theta \cos\phi & \cos\theta \sin\phi & -\sin\theta \\
   -\sin\phi           & \cos\phi            & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{x} \\ A_{y} \\ A_{z}
 \end{bmatrix}
$
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
From spherical to rectangular: \\[1ex]
$\!
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{x} \\A_{y} \\ A_{z}
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \sin\theta \cos\phi & \cos\theta \cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\
   \sin\theta \sin\phi & \cos\theta \sin\phi & \cos\phi \\
   \cos\theta          & -\sin\theta         & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
 \end{bmatrix}
$
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
From cylindrical to spherical: \\[1ex]
$\!
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{r} \\ A_{\theta} \\ A_{\phi}
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta \\ 
   \cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta \\ 
   0          & 1 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A_{\rho} \\ A_{\phi} \\ A_{z}
 \end{bmatrix}
$
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]